# Cannot use globals as default arguments in macros

Tags: jinja2

I'm adding some globals in my handler that should be available to all templates, including macros.

```
jinja_env.globals.update({
  "SOME_CONSTANT": SOME_CONSTANT_1,
})
```

This works fine when I use it inside a macro like this:

```
{% macro is_some_constant(some_str) -%}
  some_str == SOME_CONSTANT
{%- endmacro %}
```

But I get an undefined error when I try to use a global as a default arg to the macro:

```
{% macro test_something(something=SOME_CONSTANT) -%}
  ...
{%- endmacro %}
```

Result: `NameError: global name 'l_SOME_CONSTANT' is not defined`

Is this expected? I found this [related issue](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/110) which is claimed to be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/637), but still running into this. The workaround mentioned in the first link does work, but is kind of silly and annoying:

```
{% set SOME_CONSTANT = SOME_CONSTANT %}
{% macro test_something(something=SOME_CONSTANT) -%}
  ...
{%- endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I realized I'm on jinja2 v2.8, and the [fix PR](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/637) was merged into 2.9 (I think). So perhaps that fixes the problem.

For now, I'll just use the hacky workaround.